# How make "filters" in Angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Here's my situation: I have a list of objects inside a collection in the server, and I need "filter" the results in this way: "all", for "states", for "jobs", and for "jobs" inside "states".

At the moment, I have a temporary solution, using (switch) and custom querys to nodejs server, but only works for "all", and for "jobs" (cargos) or "states".

**component.ts**

```
filtroCargo(filter: string) {
    switch (filter) {
      case 'all':
        this.cdtService.getPublished().subscribe(cdts => (this.cdts = cdts));
        break;
      case 'senador':
        this.cdtService
          .getCdtFiltroCargo('senador')
          .subscribe(cdts => (this.cdts = cdts));
        break;
      case 'depFed':
        this.cdtService
          .getCdtFiltroCargo('depFed')
          .subscribe(cdts => (this.cdts = cdts));
        break;
      case 'depEst':
        this.cdtService
          .getCdtFiltroCargo('depEst')
          .subscribe(cdts => (this.cdts = cdts));
        break;
      case 'sup1':
        this.cdtService
          .getCdtFiltroCargo('sup1')
          .subscribe(cdts => (this.cdts = cdts));
        break;
      case 'sup2':
        this.cdtService
          .getCdtFiltroCargo('sup2')
          .subscribe(cdts => (this.cdts = cdts));
        break;
      case 'vGov':
        this.cdtService
          .getCdtFiltroCargo('vGov')
          .subscribe(cdts => (this.cdts = cdts));
        break;
      case 'gov':
        this.cdtService
          .getCdtFiltroCargo('gov')
          .subscribe(cdts => (this.cdts = cdts));
        break;
    }
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid conteudo">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md leftFront d-flex flex-column align-items-end border-right">
      <div class="row mb-3 pr-3">
        <select name="uf" id="uf" class="custom-select">
          <option disabled>Estado</option>
          <option *ngFor="let estado of estados | async" [ngValue]="estado">{{ estado.nome}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="row pr-3">
        <tabset [vertical]="true" type="pills" class="d-none d-md-block text-right">
          <tab heading="Todos" (select)="filtroCargo('all')"></tab>
          <tab heading="{{cargo.display}}" *ngFor="let cargo of cargos" (select)="filtroCargo(cargo.value)"></tab>
        </tabset>
        <!-- menu mobile -->
        <accordion class="d-block d-sm-none my-3">
          <accordion-group heading="Categorias" [isOpen]="isOpen" (click)="delayMenu()">
            <tabset [vertical]="true" type="pills" class="">
              <tab heading="{{cargo.display}}" *ngFor="let cargo of cargos" (select)="filtroCargo(cargo.value)"></tab>
            </tabset>
          </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md rightFront">
      <!-- *ngIf="cdt?.uf.sigla == 'RJ'" -->
      <div class="row">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let cdt of cdts">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <app-candidato-card [cdt]="cdt"></app-candidato-card>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How I could make equal to this (print of the section below): https://candidatos.novo.org.br/home ?

[image]

Comment: I think it's about time that you created a StackBlitz Project highlighting your issue.

stackblitz.com

Answer (score 2):

You're testing for equality with a string and then using that string. There's no need for that.

For example, imagine a simple function which should return the number it receives:

```
function getSelf (n: number) {
  switch (n) {
    case 1: return 1
    case 2: return 2
    case 3: return 3
  }
}
```

No need for it, right? You can just do it like this:

```
function getSelf (n: number) { return n }
```

Or, in your case:

```
  filtroCargo(filter: string) {
    switch (filter) {
      case 'all':
        this.cdtService.getPublished().subscribe(cdts => (this.cdts = cdts));
        break;
      default:
        this.cdtService
          .getCdtFiltroCargo(filter)
          .subscribe(cdts => (this.cdts = cdts));
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: thaaanks for this... cleaned my code a lot ... but I still need the other situations. I've pasted a reference link to what I need to do.

Comment: You're posted a link to some website and I have no idea what to make of it. I've posted code and asked how to get rid of repetition, which is what I've done the best I could.

Comment: I'm sorry... I edited the question, adding more information.

Comment: No, I do not expect you to build the UI for me, even because it's ready. I am simply having a question of how to filter the results in the same way that is done on the site that I have printed. If you think answering the question is to do the project for me, then just ignore it. No need to complain here in the comments. I have already thanked you for your help. However, your answer did not fill the whole situation.

Comment: If you can not understand that I've put the code I already have, the example I want to get to (the example link and the print of the specific section), and the question that says it, then start complaining about several more posts that exist on the platform. Or simply review your text interpretation concepts. Or better yet, do not waste your time or mine. I will not argue with you any more. Greetings.